# Exporting markup data in RVT/CAD format

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, revit, cad

I am using Autodesk Markupscore Extension to draw markups on 2D view. I want to create a separate rvt or CAD file for the drawn markup, which can further be used/opened in Revit soft. So the newly created 2D view(rvt/CAD) will contain only that part of 2D view which is inside the drawn markup, How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the Revit specific piece (for that I would suggest that you check out the Revit discussion forums) but if we're talking about where Forge can help, I see two options:

- you could have a Revit plugin running in the [Forge Design Automation service](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3), accepting a Revit document and some coordinates of 2D markups on the input, removing design elements that are outside of the 2D markups via Revit APIs, and generating a new Revit document on the output.
- you could customize [Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7) to hide or occlude the parts of the 2D drawings you don't want to be visible, for example, by "hiding" them (making them semi-transparent), by changing their color, or by overlaying them with another content such as a blank SVG rectangle.